# Changing Django built in admin style sheet

Tags: django, stylesheet, admin

I wish to change the built in blue colours for the admin pages. 
I used Firebug in Mozilla to try and find the colours around different style sheets I found in the Django.1-3 folder, but none seem to come up.

In what directories would I find the .css files for pages that have the header dark blue colour and the light blue table captions colour?

What actions must I take in order for the changes to work(eg. move folder to main project folder)?

Comment: What part of the admin .CSS file confused you?  Please be specific on the `.css` styles that were unclear or hard to edit.  All of these may be helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=django+admin+css

Comment: as I said, I simply want to change the default blue colours around the built in admin pages, such as login, main page, change list etc. Which files should i be looking at and how would I approach making the changes. For example changing any pre built html pages requires to copy them into the templates folder in my project. What actions besides changing the actual code are required to make changes to the .css files for the admin pages

Comment: "as I said" doesn't help.  I need more information than what you said.  Or I wouldn't have asked.  You just change the .css.  That's all.  What is confusing about changing the .css file? Can you **update** the question to clarify what steps you think you should be doing so we can comment on the steps?

Comment: I changed it now, is that better? I was simply looking for a fast response and thought a short question would be suffice. My apologies.

Comment: Premature optimization is the root of all evil.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/howto/deployment/modwsgi/#serving-the-admin-files

> The admin files live in (django/contrib/admin/static/admin) of the Django distribution.

You have the source.  You can change these files.

One common approach is to (1) copy the static admin files to a separate directory that your web server can use, (2) configure your web server to serve these files, and (3) change your `settings.py` to reflect this new location for your admin media.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/ref/settings/#admin-media-prefix

No template changes are made.

Nothing needs to be moved into your "main project folder" (whatever that might be).

Comment: I dont seem to have this directory (django/contrib/admin/static/admin)

Comment: @Angie: Keep looking.  If you have Django, you have the contributed applications.  If it really, truly does not exist, you have a serious problem and need to figure out who installed Django incorrectly.

Comment: I was downloading and installing both django and python. Is the static files for django 1.3? Because I downloaded the zip file again https://www.djangoproject.com/download/ and checked inside for the directory and there is no static folder. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: @Angie: Did you find **any** .css files?  Anywhere in the Django `/contrib/admin` tree?  Perhaps in `/contrib/admin/media`?  You are free to look around a little inside the Django distribution.  Their documentation may have "bugs" in it.  You can look at the Django documentation and post your own comment if you find that they've mislead you.

Comment: I found images that are used in the admin pages at the location \Django-1.3\django\contrib\admin\media\img\admin but changing them or deleting them didn't effect my project at all. I still couldn't find the admin\static files

Comment: @Angie: Keep looking.  The .css are there.  Your OS has numerous file search capabilities.  Linux has `find`.  Windows has something.